# How do I have a program create its own variables with Java?

Tags: java, string

I would like to start off by saying that if this is common knowledge, please forgive me and have patience. I am somewhat new to Java.
I am trying to write a program that will store many values of variables in a sort of buffer. I was wondering if there was a way to have the program "create" its own variables, and assign them to values.
Here is an Example of what I am trying to avoid:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
     public static void main(String args[]) {

        int inputCacheNumber = 0;
        //Text File:
        String userInputCache1 = null;
        String userInputCache2 = null;
        String userInputCache3 = null;
        String userInputCache4 = null;

        //Program
        while (true) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("User Input: ");
            String userInput;
            userInput = scan.nextLine();

            // This would be in the text file
            if (inputCacheNumber == 0) {
                userInputCache1 = userInput;
                inputCacheNumber++;
                System.out.println(userInputCache1);
            } else if (inputCacheNumber == 1) {
                userInputCache2 = userInput;
                inputCacheNumber++;
            } else if (inputCacheNumber == 2) {
                userInputCache3 = userInput;
                inputCacheNumber++;
            } else if (inputCacheNumber == 3) {
                userInputCache4 = userInput;
                inputCacheNumber++;
            }
            // And so on

        }

    }
}
```

So just to try to summarize, I would like to know if there is a way for a program to set an unlimited number of user input values to String values. I am wondering if there is a way I can avoid predefining all the variables it may need.
Thanks for reading, and your patience and help!
~Rane

Comment: You can use a container, google "Java containers" for more info.

Comment: Have a look at the [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/), in particular, you might want to look at `List` (and `ArrayList`).  Depending on the complexity of the information you are storing, you might need to create a custom object to maintain the common properties for each object, but that might beyond what you are asking

Comment: @MadProgrammer is my answer ok? I feel it is too shabby

Comment: @KickButtowski No, I think it covers the basics as far as the OP is concerned.  Throw in a link to [The List Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) and [The List Implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html) to encourgae there own further learning and I think you'd be done

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Array List` data structure.

> The ArrayList class extends AbstractList and implements the List
>   interface. **ArrayList supports dynamic arrays that can grow as needed.**

For example:

```
List<String> userInputCache = new ArrayList<>();
```

and when you want to add each input into your array like

```
if (inputCacheNumber == 0) {
    userInputCache.add(userInput); // <----- here
    inputCacheNumber++;
}
```

If you want to traverse your array list you can do as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < userInputCache.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(" your user input is " + userInputCache.get(i));
}
```

or you can use `enhanced for loop`

```
for(String st : userInputCache) {
    System.out.println("Your user input is " + st);
}
```

Note: it is better to put your `Scanner` in your `try catch block with resource` so you will not be worried if it is close or not at the end.

For example:

```
try(Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    /*
    **whatever code you have you put here**
    Good point for MadProgrammer:
    Just beware of it, that's all. A lot of people have multiple stages in their   
    programs which may require them to create a new Scanner AFTER the try-block
    */
 } catch(Exception e) {
 }
```

**For more info on ArrayList**

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm

Comment: Just be careful when `Scanner` uses `System.in` as you really don't want to close the stdin stream ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer but it will be closed at the end of the processes am I right? I never had any issue with it

Comment: If you never use it again, it should be fine, but if your program then needs to do something else with the `stdin`, you'd be in trouble...

Comment: I will try to do what ever i want in try block so I think I gonna be safe

Comment: Just beware of it, that's all.  A lot of people have multiple stages in their programs which may require them to create a new `Scanner` AFTER the try-block, just so you're not leading the poor OP down a path that won't understand :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer i put your comment in my answer hope it makes it better

Comment: This is a nit-pick, but some other people might jump on, object instances should start with lowercase characters, `UserInputCache` should be `userInputCache`. Check out [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) for more details ;)